# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve any module

Tags: reactjs, import, react-query

I can't import modules and keep getting errors. For example
react-query
I'd trying declare module in react-app-env.d.ts. But it also don't help
Errors:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@tanstack/react-query-devtools' in '/Users/hauntme/Desktop/projects/typing-hero/src'
WARNING in [eslint]
```

```
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->

<!-- language: lang-html -->

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
    import React from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
    import './index.css';
    import App from './App';
    import {QueryClient, QueryClientProvider} from '@tanstack/react-query'
    import {ReactQueryDevtools} from '@tanstack/react-query-devtools'
    const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
      document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
    );
    const queryClient = new QueryClient()
    root.render(
      <React.StrictMode>
        <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
            <App />
        <ReactQueryDevtools/>
      </QueryClientProvider>
      </React.StrictMode>
    );

    // this react-app-env.d.ts
    declare module '@tanstack/react-query'
    declare module '@tanstack/react-query-devtools'
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xo1O9.png)

Comment: Did you try to run `npm install`?